# Finding <caption class="table-title">

Tags: python, html, pandas

so I have written a script to scrape tables from a website and saves these to an Excel sheet:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from pandas import ExcelWriter
import os.path
path = "C:...."
url= 'https://zoek.officielebekendmakingen.nl/kst-35570-2.html'
page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')

tables_df = pd.read_html(url, attrs = {'class': 'kio2 portrait'})

tables = soup.find_all('table', class_="kio2 portrait")

titles = []
for table in tables:
    print(table)
    title = table.find_all("caption", class_="table-title")
    titles.append(title)
titles = []

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('output.xlsx')
for i, df in enumerate(tables_df, 1):
    df.to_excel(writer, index=True,sheet_name=f'sheetName_{i}')
writer.save()
```

Which works, but now I want to find all titles of these table so I can give each sheet this title. For example, the first table has the following text of which I am interested:

`<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="kio2 portrait" summary="Tabel 1.1 Budgettaire kerngegevens"><caption class="table-title">Tabel 1.1 Budgettaire kerngegevens</caption>`

Now I want to scrape the part between `<caption class="table-title">` and `</caption>`. Or, which is also a possibility, use the summary element. How can I achieve this? I have tried it within the code but I do not find anything yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```py
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from pandas import ExcelWriter


url = "https://zoek.officielebekendmakingen.nl/kst-35570-2.html"
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).text, "html.parser")

writer = pd.ExcelWriter("output.xlsx")
for i, table in enumerate(soup.find_all("table", class_="kio2 portrait"), 1):
    df = pd.read_html(str(table))[0]

    caption = table.get("summary", "").replace(":", "").strip()
    # some tables doesn't contain summary, so make generic sheet name:
    if not caption:
        caption = f"table {i}"

    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=caption)

writer.save()
```

This creates `output.xlsx` with 185 sheets (at least opening it in my Libreoffice):

[image]